# Pandas: select column with most unique values

Tags: python, pandas, unique, multiple-columns

I have a pandas DataFrame and want to find select the column with the most unique values.
I already filtered the unique values with nunique(). How can I now choose the column with the highest nunique()?

This is my code so far:

```
numeric_columns = df.select_dtypes(include = (int or float))
    unique = []
    for column in numeric_columns:
        unique.append(numeric_columns[column].nunique())
```

I later need to filter all the columns of my dataframe depending on this column(most uniques)

Comment: Oh and as an output for unique I get [84, 77, 35, 84] so I should choose the first "84"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) with `np.number`, then get [`DataFrame.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) with column by maximal value by [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[1,2,2,2], 'c':list('abcd')})
print (df)
   a  b  c
0  1  1  a
1  2  2  b
2  3  2  c
3  4  2  d

numeric = df.select_dtypes(include = np.number)

nu = numeric.nunique().idxmax()
print (nu)
a
```